# Swig wrapper for golang

Tags: c++, go, swig, unique-ptr

I'm having trouble to use swig to wrap a c++ library for golang. Here is my c++ header file.

```
class Builder {
 public:
  explicit Builder(int i):counters(i){} 
  void Init(); 
  void CreateCounters(vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>* s);
  bool CreateEntry(string* primary_key);
 private:
  std::shared_ptr<hash_set<string>> ids;
  int counters;
};
```

I just want to wrap Builder class and its constructor, Init() and CreateEntry function. Here is my swig API

```
%{
#include "builder.h"
%}

%ignoreall

%unignore Builder;
%unignore Builder::Init();
%unignore CreateEntry(string* primary_key);

%include "builder.h"

%unignoreall
```

But when I compile I get error pointing to the CreateCounters function which has a argument of unique_ptr vector. Can anyone tell me whats wrong in here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please include the entire error message in your post.

Comment: I'm using swig in internal system. Though the error message:
    `builder.h:: Error: Syntax error in input(3)`
Line 5 points to the CreateCounters function.

Comment: Is your "internal system" passing the `-c++` argument to swig to tell it that it is wrapping C++?

Comment: Also, AFAIK `%ignoreall` etc. are not valid SWIG directives, in any case they will likely need a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your swig file doesn't have a module name. Try this...

```
%module builder
%{
#include "builder.h"
%}

%ignoreall

%unignore Builder;
%unignore Builder::Init();
%unignore CreateEntry(string* primary_key);

%include "builder.h"

%unignoreall
```

The module name translates to the name of the package your wrapped code resides in.

Also for c++ code, ensure your swig file is named something like 'builder.swigcxx' the extension is important as otherwise it'll assume you're wrapping pure C.